# Сохранить дамп сегмента кода на жесткий диск с помощью ассемблеровской вставки

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу (лабораторная работа), в которой нужна ассемблерная вставка. С ассемблером я сам не знаком, поэтому могу ошибиться с формулировкой.

В общем, нужно, чтобы ассемблеровская вставка сохраняла дамп сегмента кода на жесткий диск.

В интернете нашел кусок программы, которая шифрует сегмент кода:

```
use32

;ROR section
mov ebx, ${start+pack_len-1}
mov ecx, ${pack_len-1}

ror_loop:
mov al, byte [ebx]
ror al, ${key_encode}
mov byte [ebx], al

cmp ecx, 0
jz stop_loop

dec ebx
dec ecx
jmp ror_loop

stop_loop:

;GO OEP

push ${original_eop}
ret
```

Дело в том, что ассемблеровская вставка, которую я привел выше, используется в программе на python. Только, эта вставка шифрует сегмент кода, а мне нужно, чтобы она сохраняла в файл сегмент кода.
А так как я в ассемблере вообще не имею опыта, прошу вас помочь.

Comment: @Pinkibosh, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @ReinRaus это очень интересный вопрос. Я просто не слышал о трансляторах с ассемблерными вставками на FASM.

Comment: @alexlz: А в чём проблема? Скомпилировать в объектный файл, подключить на этапе компоновки, делов-то.

Comment: @VladD Видимо я сильно отстал от жизни. Я-то всё время считал, что с ассемблерными вставками разбирается компилятор, а не линковщик.

Comment: @VladD википедия тоже отстала: [Ассемблерная вставка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @alexlz: если компилятор не поддерживает вставки в формате FASM, компоновка с объектным модулем всё ещё работает.

Comment: @VladD уровень обсуждения повышается.

    Не на скачках, а в преферанс, не 10000, а 100 рублей и не выиграл, а проиграл.

Тут недавно уже с Мечтой-Ребёнком на эту тему дискутировали.

Comment: @alexlz, технически это может выглядеть так: есть питоновский модуль, который принимает строку кода на асме, передает эту строку фасму, он ее компилирует и возвращает машинный код, который уже можно запускать (упрощенно). По сути это не ассемблерная вставка, а компиляция в рантайме.